# Emulating multiple includes for variables in string

Tags: php

This is a simplified example.

Attempting to generate sentences with variables in strings that change on each iteration.
For example:

```
/*
stringText.php
<?php
$sentences = [
"Hello there, $name.",
"Your gender is $gender",
"Are you $age years old?",
]
?>
*/
$attributes = [
    ['name'=>'anna','age'=>14, 'gender'=>'female'],
    ['name'=>'frank','age'=>16, 'gender'=>'male'],
    ['name'=>'dan','age'=>15, 'gender'=>'male'],
    ['name'=>'lara','age'=>16, 'gender'=>'female'],
];

foreach($attributes as $val){
    $name = $val['name'];
    $age = $val['age'];
    $gender = $val['gender'];
    include('stringText.php');
    echo $sentences[rand(0,2)].'<br/>';
}
```

Is there a way to do this without calling the 'include' each time? Maybe storing the value of include in a variable or something similar?

Comment: Have you considered making a function which takes an array and returns the sentences with the values interpolated? Then you could just call the function multiple times instead of using include.

Comment: I had considered it, but with the values and flexibility it wouldn't really be a practical solution.

Comment: I think it would be a practical solution actually. That's kind of the entire purpose of functions - to make a piece of code which is re-usable, but can produce slightly different results each time based on values which are input into it. What you've done with include() is just a very crude way of implementing the same concept. Functions are the generally accepted and more efficient way of doing it

Answer (score 2):

You've got two options - make your `$sentences` variable a function and pass the vales to it and return a single value;

```
<?php
function sentences($name, $gender, $age){
    $sentences = [
    "Hello there, $name.",
    "Your gender is $gender",
    "Are you $age years old?",
    ];
    return $sentences[rand(0,2)];
}

$attributes = [
    ['name'=>'anna','age'=>14, 'gender'=>'female'],
    ['name'=>'frank','age'=>16, 'gender'=>'male'],
    ['name'=>'dan','age'=>15, 'gender'=>'male'],
    ['name'=>'lara','age'=>16, 'gender'=>'female'],
];

include('stringText.php');
foreach($attributes as $val){
    $name = $val['name'];
    $age = $val['age'];
    $gender = $val['gender'];
    echo sentences($val['name'],$val['gender'],$val['age']).'<br/>';
}
```

You could pass the `$val` array and reference to the key/values directly in the `sentences()` function which gives more flexibility in the future.

Or, you can use `str_replace()` to replace tokens in strings. For example;

```
<?php

$sentences = [
"Hello there, {{name}}",
"Your gender is {{gender}}",
"Are you {{age}} years old?",
];

$attributes = [
    ['name'=>'anna','age'=>14, 'gender'=>'female'],
    ['name'=>'frank','age'=>16, 'gender'=>'male'],
    ['name'=>'dan','age'=>15, 'gender'=>'male'],
    ['name'=>'lara','age'=>16, 'gender'=>'female'],
];

// include('stringText.php');
foreach($attributes as $val){
    $name = $val['name'];
    $age = $val['age'];
    $gender = $val['gender'];
    $sentence = $sentences[rand(0,2)];
    $sentence = str_replace(array('{{name}}','{{gender}}','{{age}}'),array($val['name'],$val['gender'],$val['age']),$sentence);
    echo $sentence.'<br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do like:

**string_text.php**

```
<?php
function sentences($name, $age, $gender)
  $s = ["Hello there, $name.", "Your gender is $gender.", "You are $age years old."];
  return $s[rand(0, 2)];
}
?>
```

**other_page.php**

```
<?php
require_once 'string_text.php';
$attributes = [
  ['name'=>'Anna','age'=>14, 'gender'=>'female'],
  ['name'=>'Frank','age'=>16, 'gender'=>'male'],
  ['name'=>'Dan','age'=>15, 'gender'=>'male'],
  ['name'=>'Lara','age'=>16, 'gender'=>'female']
];
foreach($attributes as $a){
  $r[] = sentences($a['name'], $a['age'], $a['gender']);
}
echo implode('<br />', $r);
?>
```

Well, let's be realistic... I would handle things, that should or do not require Server action, with Client-side JavaScript.

Comment: Unfortunately I can not use javascript since it is through a pdf generator which is solely using php.